# Pandas calculate the winrate for particular group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this table [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A28Hp.png)

I want to create new column with winrate of every team, how can i do this?

Comment: Since you're new in SO, I'd suggest you also post any attempts you've made.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have this data in a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

# some data in a dict
data = [{'team': 'BOOM Esports', 'IS_WIN': False, 'count': 9},
        {'team': 'BOOM Esports', 'IS_WIN': True, 'count': 5},
        {'team': 'BetBoom Team', 'IS_WIN': False, 'count': 7},
        {'team': 'BetBoom Team', 'IS_WIN': True, 'count': 9}]

# creating dataframe with dict
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You could work with `df.groupby`:

```
matches_won = df[df['IS_WIN'] == True].groupby('team')['count'].sum()
matches = df.groupby('team')['count'].sum()

winning_rate = matches_won / matches
```

Output:

```
print(winning_rate)

# team
# BOOM Esports    0.357143
# BetBoom Team    0.562500
# Name: count, dtype: float64
```